# uploading file to public folder on vercel returns error permission error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

When i try to upload file to public folder on vercel I get below error.

```
⨯ [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/var/task/public/bb17ad93-017f-4fdf-a2db-713d9a390143.webp'] {
  errno: -30,
  code: 'EROFS',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/var/task/public/bb17ad93-017f-4fdf-a2db-713d9a390143.webp'
}
```

Here is my `api/upload` code.

```
import { writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { join } from "path";
import sharp from 'sharp';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const file: File | null = formData.get('file') as unknown as File;

  if (!file) return NextResponse.json({ success: false });

  const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();
  const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);
  
  const pngBuffer = await sharp(buffer).toFormat('webp').toBuffer();
  const outputPath = `${uuidv4()}.webp`;

  const path = join(process.cwd(), "public", outputPath);

  await writeFile(path, pngBuffer);
  console.log(`open ${path} to see the uploaded file`);

  return new NextResponse(
    JSON.stringify({ success: true, message: "body.message", image: outputPath }),
    { status: 200, headers: { 'content-type': 'image/png' } }
  );
}
```

above code works perfectly fine in my dev environment(local computer) but after deploying to vercel it throws that error.

I am using `nextjs 13 app router`.

Comment: Looks like simple permission issue so check the permission for /var/task/public/ path, give read and write permission to it.

Comment: @Vipertecpro How can I change permission on vercel server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't have access to write data in that folder. Only `/tmp` folder is available [Reference](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/5320). And as its a temporary folder, if you want to persist the file then better to store somewhere, probably in S3. You can check the example [here](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions#using-temporary-storage)

Also, you can try **Vercel Blob** to store data. You can find more here: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-upload-and-store-files-with-vercel

Comment: I tried with `/tmp` folder but I still get the same error. Can you help with proper working coding example?

Comment: When I change this line `const path = join(process.cwd(), "public", outputPath);` to `const path = join("/", "tmp", outputPath);` then when I try to access and and send it to front end using this line `return new NextResponse(
    JSON.stringify({ success: true, message: "body.message", image: `${path}` }),
    { status: 200, headers: { 'content-type': 'image/png' } }
  );` It does not work. How can I access this file from `tmp` folder after uploading?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? Access to that folder will be lost once the API execution is complete (as its tmp folder). @26ph19

Answer (score 0):

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import sharp from 'sharp';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export async function POST(request) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const file = formData.get('file');

  if (!file) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: false }), {
      status: 400,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }

  const fileBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
  const imagePath = join('/tmp', `${uuidv4()}.webp`);

  await fs.writeFile(imagePath, Buffer.from(fileBuffer));

  // Clean up temp file
  await fs.unlink(imagePath);

  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({ success: true, message: 'File uploaded successfully' }),
    { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
  );
}
```